# How does one find out what the total reputation was at any given moment in time?

Tags: feature-request, reputation

How does one know how much reputation did he/she have in a given (past) period?

For example, how do I find how much reputation I had in 2015, July?
I know how to find how much reputation you got for a given period, but not how to find the total you had at that given moment.

[image]

Reputation points got in a given day/period. What about the total reputation you had at that very moment?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know if there's any pretty way to obtain this information, but it can be retrieved easily by looking at [your personal reputation audit](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation).

When you are logged in, that link will take you a text file containing your entire reputation history. On each specific date where you have earned reputation, there is a running total out to the side.

[image]

Comment: Cool. Good enough, thanks!